# Determine whether each of the following transformations $T$ has an inverse and, if so, determine the action of $T^{-1}.$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra

1) $T: R^3 \to R^3\quad T(x,y,z) = (x+y, y+z, z+x)$

2) $T: M_{2\times 2} \to M_{2\times 2}\quad T\left(\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix} a-c & b-d \\ 2a-c & 2b-d \end{bmatrix}$

3) $T: P_2[x] \to R^3\quad T(a+bx+cx^2) = (a-c, 2b, a+c)$

I know for the 1) that we have to find the augmented matrix then find the det. I found det (A)=2 so T is invertible. But I'm totally lost after.

Comment: 1) After showing that $T$ Is invertible, we define $T^{-1}(x,y,z) = \{(a,b,c) \in \mathbb R^3 : T(a,b,c) = (x,y,z)\}.$ But:
$$ T(a,b,c) = (a+b, b+c, a+c) = (x,y,z).$$

Defining the $a,b,c$ in terms of $x,y,z$ solving the following system, will give us the inverse, i.e.

$\left.
\begin{array}{l}
a+b = x\\
b+c = y\\
a+c = z
\end{array}
\right\}
$

Comment: Should I do the same for the others too? Because my problem is how to find the augmented matrix, I know how how to find the determinant. I have problem finding the augmented matrix for the 3). The 2) is pretty straightforward

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you are talking about when you 're saying "augmented matrix".

Comment: In order to find the determinant we need to find the matrix. For example 1) I got the matrix A=[1 1 0] [0 1 1] [1 0 1], then det (A)= 2

Comment: Well, I don't know if this matrix is called augmented (I don't think so, but anyway). What I think you are doing is the following:
$$(x+y, y+z, x+z) = x(1,0,1) + y(1,1,0) + z(0,1,1), \quad x,y,z \in \mathbb R.$$

So, you are saying that $\operatorname{Im T} = \langle(1,0,1), (1,1,0), (0,1,1)\rangle,$ i.e. $\operatorname{Im T} $ is spanned by these 3 vectors. Since they are linearly independent (by finding the above determinant), you have shown that $T$ is surjection. But you haven't proven that $T$ is $1-1.$

Comment: Sorry to bother with all these questions. But for the 2) since a,b,c, d are not actual numbers. How can I tell if T is invertible or not

Comment: I think it might be easier to determine whether or not the kernel of each transformation is trivial: see if there’s anything besides the zero vector that gets mapped to zero.

Comment: @amd can you just help me with this one? I know how to find T^-1 already.

Comment: It's alright! Did you try anything? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to convert each of these transformations into a matrix, 
I think it’s much easier to go back to basic definitions and test their kernels directly. Recall the the kernel of a linear transformation is the set of vectors that are mapped to zero. A linear transformation is invertible if and only if its kernel is trivial—consists only of the zero vector.

Let’s take the last transformation. We want to know if there are any non-zero polynomials that get mapped to zero by $T$. For such a polynomial we would have $(a-c,2b, a+c)=(0,0,0)$. This obviously requires $b=0$. From the other two components, we have both $a-c=0$ and $a+c=0$, which means that $a=c=0$, so the transformation is invertible. To find the inverse, solve $(a-c,2b,a+c)=(x,y,z)$ for $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Can you do part 2 now?